# ^[A-Z](([A-Z_0-9])*[^_])?$ wrong match

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

Need a regex for Java generic type parameters, so i've tried with :

```
^[A-Z](([A-Z_0-9])*[^_])?$
```

means the type name should have 1 or more characters all uppercase and digits, it's possible
to use '_' as separator, but not at the end, f.e. 'TT_A9'
But to my surprise my regex tool shows a match for 'Aa' or 'AAa' or 'AA-'
I wrote a simple test class to check :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTestPatternMatcher { 

public static final String test = "AA-";

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z](([A-Z_0-9])*[^_])?$");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
   System.out.println("Matches ? " + matcher.matches());
  }
}
```

Output :

```
AA- Matches ? true
```

It's also true for AAa, but not for AA_
It works if i use the regex `^[A-Z](([A-Z_0-9])*[^_a-z-])?$`
but i don't understand why i need to use 'a-z' and '-' as exclusion,
when i'm only looking for uppercase characters !?

Comment: `[^_]` means "any character except underscore", which includes hyphen.

Comment: @chrylis good catch, a classic gotcha ;-)  my knowledge of regex is a bit rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) - as in your original pattern, `[^_]` - you tell the regex to consume a character other than the one defined in the class. So, your regex actually requires at least 2 chars, the first one being an uppercase ASCII letter, and any char but `_` at the end, and there can be any  characters in the `_`, `0-9` and `A-Z` ranges in between.

You are looking for a [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) anchored at the end of the string:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]*$(?<!_)
                 ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQsiga/1)

It will fail all matches where the `_` is at the end of the string. The `_` is not consumed, it is only checked for presence, and thus the pattern will accept (match) a 1-char string starting with an uppercase ASCII letter and optionally followed with the characters from the ranges defined in the `[A-Z_0-9]` character class.

I also suggest removing all redundant groupings (you are not using the captured subtexts anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, How to adjust the regex to prevent double underscores, means A__A should not be allowed, whereas A_A or A_9 is valid.

Comment: Then it is easier to revamp the pattern into `^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: Thanks again !! To allow a single uppercase character also i created a second regex like that  ^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)?$

Comment: It is almost equal to my suggestion, the only difference is that you only allow 1 `_` symbol since you used `?` quantifier at the end. `*` matches 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: Right, that's not what i want. Need to allow a single character, but optionally multiple '_' as separators should be valid also. With my added ? T_T_T would not be valid anymore. And also is it possible to have another similar regex that additionally enforces 2 characters ?

Comment: What does it mean "enforces 2 characters"? Requires the string to be of length 2 or more? Or to require at least 2 uppercase letters in it?

Comment: I need two flavors of that rule a) 1 uppercase chararacter, otionally followed by more uppercase characters and digits, underscore allowed as separator, but not multiple underscores and no underscores at start or end. 2) like rule 1) but the string has to have the length of 2 or more.

Comment: For the first type, I think you already have a pattern, to make the second, just add `(?=.{2,}$)` after `^` (or even `(?=.{2})` should do).

Comment: Thanks a bunch !   (?=.{2}) is perfect.